# new c++ error with file

Tags: c++, console, cout

I am 100% new at c++ so bear with me :)

I am getting an error with this file and not sure why. any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "hi" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

------------ Build: Debug in 1600 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)-------------

```
g++  -o bin/Debug/1600 obj/Debug/main.o obj/Debug/src/test.o obj/Debug/test03.o   
duplicate symbol _main in:
    obj/Debug/main.o
    obj/Debug/test03.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You are linking together three files, but only show the source of one. I guess you use some IDE and somehow botched your project setup. Try creating a new and clean project.

Comment: It may expect you to declare arguments for `main()`, as in `int main(int argc, char* argv)` because you can have multiple functions with the same name as long as they have different arguments.

Comment: Have you created a new project, with only a single `main`? It sounds like you have defined `main` multiple times, so it's likely your project has multiple files with more than one `main`

Comment: `main` with no arguments is perfectly legal C++

Comment: @vacuumhead That does not apply to `main`. There can be only one.

Comment: @Tas I created a project that has main.cpp, test03.cpp. btw I am using codeblocks on mac. perhaps my setup is bad and I need to start over. Like I said I am a total beginner to c++.

Comment: @BaummitAugen are you saying for every main program (even if it's a simple .cpp file) I need a new project? I suppose I am used to Java where I can have a project and package but with different classes. Maybe it is totally different with c++. appreciate the guidance and help

Comment: you can only have one `main()` in a project

Comment: @user9676458363 Probably depends on the IDE, maybe you can configure it to have a project with several different executables. But yeah, generally, you must have exactly one `main` in a program, and I guess the default is to treat each project as a single program.

Comment: @BaummitAugen ah okay that clears it up. Thank you!

Comment: You can only have one `main()` in a project, but you can compile a `cpp` file without having it in a project with Codeblocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source files symbols are created. `main` in the .cpp file becomes `_main` as a symbol. During linking there can be only one `main` function, hence only one `_main` symbol is expected and allowed.

---

You have three object files that were created:

- obj/Debug/main.o which contains `main`
- obj/Debug/src/test.o
- obj/Debug/test03.o which **also contains** `main`

Probably because you have a .cpp file for each of them and the command line or IDE you are using asked for them all to be compiled.

```
duplicate symbol _main
```

The text above is telling you that the linker (trying to make sense of all the compiled object (.o) files) found more than one `main`.

---

So the solution is to look at your IDE settings and remove the other files (or at least remove `main` from the other files) because you are only interested in compiling the one source file.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell what you're running from the question.

Here is how to build a simple C++ program using gcc

In
`my_program.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "hi" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

To compile to object files type

`g++ -c my_program.cpp`

To link (you'd normally have more files here)

```
g++ -o my_program my_program.o
```

So, this isn't very fun so most people use a build system like make, cmake, msbuild or whatever the CLion IDE uses.